# div to be show on the Top Right Corner irrespective of resolution and when browser is Minimized and it should not overlay on the Left hand side div

Tags: jquery, css, html, css-float

The CSS:

```
.divStudents{
  float: left;
  width :83%
}

.divSelection{
  float :left;
  width:17%;
  position : absolute;
  left: 1150 px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="divStudents"></div>
<div class="divSelection"></div>
```

I have two Div 1. divStudent 2. divSelection in my Webpage with the above classes.

When I load my page only divSelection will be displayed and it should be shown on the Top-Right corner of the page.
I have some controls(dropdown and radio buttons) in my divSelection, depending on these controls divStudents will be loaded on remaining part of the page (i.e Left hand side of the page).

Every thing is working fine in normal resolution, But when the resolution changes to lower resolution or if I minimize my browser the divSelection is  showing on the Top Right hand side of the page with scroll bar and some times its not visible.

I tried the below solution but it is giving overlay problem.

Using right:0 instead of left : 1150 px in divSelection but it overlaying in the divStudent.

Is there a way to achive this.

Answer (score 0):

Change css

```
.divSelection{
  float :left;
  width:17%;
  position : absolute;
  left: 1150 px;
}
```

to

```
.divSelection{
  float :right;
  width:17%;
}
```

it will be bound to be on the right side and width will also remain adjusted because of the percentages . see if it helps

Comment: Thanks lopa, Your solution almost fixed my issue. But only thing is now I am getting Horizontal scroll bar, when I minimize my browser to half of the monitor screen. And divSelection part is  hiding towards right hand side.

Comment: things are actually getting pushed apart . give some max width to both the divs. so that they stay together . be sure to keep the max width in proper proportions to fit the screen . and inside the divselection and divstdents apply percentages so that the content does not force them to widen up when compressed.